# D3.js Zooming and panning a collapsible tree diagram

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming, pan

I'm using D3.js to plot a collapsible tree diagram like in the [example](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html). It's working mostly well, but the diagram might change dramatically in size when it enters its normal function (ie instead of the few nodes I have now, I'll have a *lot* more).

I wanted to make the SVG area scroll, I've tried everything I found online to make it work, but with no success. The best I got working was using the `d3.behaviour.drag`, in which I drag the whole diagram around. It is far from optimal and glitches a lot, but it is kinda usable.

Even so, I'm trying to clean it up a little bit and I realised the `d3.behaviour.zoom` can also be used to *pan* the SVG area, according to the API docs.

**Question:** Can anyone explain how to adapt it to my code?

I would like to be able to *pan* the SVG area with the diagram, if possible making it react to some misuses, namely, trying to pan the diagram out of the viewport, and enabling to zoom to the maximum viewport's dimensions...

This is my code so far:

```
var realWidth = window.innerWidth;
var realHeight = window.innerHeight;

function load(){
    callD3();
}

var m = [40, 240, 40, 240],
    w = realWidth -m[0] -m[0],
    h = realHeight -m[0] -m[2],
    i = 0,
    root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([h, w]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var vis = d3.select("#box").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("class","svg_container")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h)
    .style("overflow", "scroll")
    .style("background-color","#EEEEEE")
  .append("svg:g")
    .attr("class","drawarea")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")")
    ;

var botao = d3.select("#form #button");

function callD3() {
//d3.json(filename, function(json) {
d3.json("D3_NEWCO_tree.json", function(json) {
  root = json;
  d3.select("#processName").html(root.text);
  root.x0 = h / 2;
  root.y0 = 0;

  botao.on("click", function(){toggle(root); update(root);});

  update(root);  
});

function update(source) {
  var duration = d3.event && d3.event.altKey ? 5000 : 500;

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse();

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 50; });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
      .on("click", function(d) { toggle(d); update(d); });

  nodeEnter.append("svg:circle")
        .attr("r", function(d){ 
                    return  Math.sqrt((d.part_cc_p*1))+4;
        })
      .attr("class", function(d) { return "level"+d.part_level; })
      .style("stroke", function(d){
        if(d._children){return "blue";}
      })    
      ;

  nodeEnter.append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -((Math.sqrt((d.part_cc_p*1))+6)+this.getComputedTextLength() ) : Math.sqrt((d.part_cc_p*1))+6; })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -7 : 0; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { 
        if(d.part_level>0){return d.name;}
        else
            if(d.part_multi>1){return "Part " + d.name+ " ["+d.part_multi+"]";}
            else{return "Part " + d.name;}
         })
        .attr("title", 
            function(d){ 
                var node_type_desc;
                if(d.part_level!=0){node_type_desc = "Labour";}else{node_type_desc = "Component";}
                return ("Part Name: "+d.text+"<br/>Part type: "+d.part_type+"<br/>Cost so far: "+d3.round(d.part_cc, 2)+"&euro;<br/>"+"<br/>"+node_type_desc+" cost at this node: "+d3.round(d.part_cost, 2)+"&euro;<br/>"+"Total cost added by this node: "+d3.round(d.part_cost*d.part_multi, 2)+"&euro;<br/>"+"Node multiplicity: "+d.part_multi);
        })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
        .attr("r", function(d){ 
            return  Math.sqrt((d.part_cc_p*1))+4;
        })
      .attr("class", function(d) { return "level"+d.part_level; })
      .style("stroke", function(d){
        if(d._children){return "blue";}else{return null;}
      })
      ;

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .remove();

    nodeExit.select("circle")
        .attr("r", function(d){ 
            return  Math.sqrt((d.part_cc_p*1))+4;
        });

  nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = vis.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(tree.links(nodes), function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("svg:path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
    .transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .remove();

    $('svg text').tipsy({
        fade:true,
        gravity: 'nw', 
        html:true
    });

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });

    var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
        .origin(function() { 
            var t = d3.select(this);
            return {x: t.attr("x"), y: t.attr("y")};
        })
        .on("drag", dragmove);

    d3.select(".drawarea").call(drag);

}

// Toggle children.
function toggle(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }

}

function dragmove(){
    d3.transition(d3.select(".drawarea"))
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.x +"," + d3.event.y + ")"); 
}
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can see (most of) a working implementation here: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/fF4L4/2/

The key pieces here:

- Call `d3.behavior.zoom()` on the `svg` element. This requires the `svg` element to have `pointer-events: all` set. You can also call this on a subelement, but I don't see a reason if you want the whole thing to pan and zoom, since you basically want the whole SVG area to respond to pan/zoom events.

  ```
  d3.select("svg")
      .call(d3.behavior.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([0.5, 5])
        .on("zoom", zoom));
  ```
- Setting `scaleExtent` here gives you the ability to limit the zoom scale. You can set it to `[1, 1]` to disable zooming entirely, or set it programmatically to the max size of your content, if that's what you want (I wasn't sure exactly what was desired here).
- The `zoom` function is similar to your `dragmove` function, but includes the scale factor and sets limits on the pan offset (as far as I can tell, d3 doesn't have any built-in `panExtent` support):

  ```
  function zoom() {
      var scale = d3.event.scale,
          translation = d3.event.translate,
          tbound = -h * scale,
          bbound = h * scale,
          lbound = (-w + m[1]) * scale,
          rbound = (w - m[3]) * scale;
      // limit translation to thresholds
      translation = [
          Math.max(Math.min(translation[0], rbound), lbound),
          Math.max(Math.min(translation[1], bbound), tbound)
      ];
      d3.select(".drawarea")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + translation + ")" +
                " scale(" + scale + ")");
  }
  ```

  (To be honest, I don't think I have the logic quite right here for the correct left and right thresholds - this doesn't seem to limit dragging properly when zoomed in. Left as an exercise for the reader :).)
- To make things simpler here, it helps to have the `g.drawarea` element not have an initial transform - so I added another `g` element to the outer wrappers to set the margin offset:

  ```
  vis // snip
    .append("svg:g")
      .attr("class","drawarea")
    .append("svg:g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")");
  ```

The rest of the changes here are just to make your code work better in JSFiddle. There are a few missing details here, but hopefully this is enough to get you started.

Comment: Many kudos for you, Mr. Rabinowitz... Excelent job, thank you! Works like a charm! My attempts here were failing precisely because of aplying `d3.behavior.zoom` to the wrong wrapper - it just kept skipping around like crazy... But this works really well (even if a bit slower/heavier on the browser)...

Comment: Very useful, apart from the margin array that is unclear

Comment: Hi - I am interested to use the zoom functionality in a way where there will always be text of fixed size no matter the zoom. So if there are more branches, and user zooms out, the branches get too small now and too many. I want to remove some of them and leave only as needed as the remaining branches to have readeable size. You think this would be possible?